# C# Delegate events bad practice?

Tags: c#

I use a lot of custom events in my code, and have been declaring them like this

```
public delegate void ImageDownloadingEvent(Waypoint waypoint);
public event ImageDownloadingEvent ImageDownloading;
```

then firing them like this

```
if (ImageDownloading != null)
    ImageDownloading(waypoint);
```

What I'd like to know is, is this bad practice? Or a bad way of doing things? If so, why? And what would be a better approach?

Thanks for any help, just trying to improve my coding skills

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it's up to you to decide if events are the right pattern to use for a given scenario. Like anything, they can be used correctly or they can become a code smell. You can use a delegate of your own declaration, or one of the more generic ones like `Func`, `EventHandler`, or `Action` if you don't want to declare a new type for every event.

Your use of events is mostly correct. You want to copy the handler to a local. Eric Lippert has an explanation why [on his blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/04/29/events-and-races/).

So it becomes this:

```
var imageDownloading = ImageDownloading;
if (imageDownloading != null)
    imageDownloading(waypoint);
```

The C# 6 compiler [can do this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802602.aspx) for you like so:

```
ImageDownloading?.Invoke(waypoint);
```

In this case the compiler knows that it should make a local copy, first.

Comment: That code is only necessary if the event is going to be accessed from multiple threads at the same time, which is pretty rarely a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like that, although in a multi-threaded environment the way you are raising them has the potential for a race condition. Therefore, the recommended way to raise an event is actually

```
var handler = ImageDownloading;
if (handler != null) handler(waypoint);
```

With C# 6 that can be a bit more concise using the null-conditional operator:

```
ImageDownloading?.Invoke(waypoint);
```

Again, only relevant when multi-threading is a concern. Most code isn't built for that case anyway.

Then there is the question whether you want to use custom delegates for every event, or custom `EventArgs` for every event (and declare them as `EventHandler<T>`). That's entirely up to you, but it *is* sort of a convention in .NET.